# Getting "Wrong number of arguments to IF..." error

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to create a logic in google sheets. But getting the error "Wrong number of arguments to IF. Expected between 2 and 3 arguments, but received 4 arguments."

I have tried this formula. It works if the number is upto 45000. It shows error if the number goes byound that.

IF(B4<20000, 0, IF(B4>20000, ROUND(IF(B4<34286,685,IF(B4<45714,1715,IF(B4<57143,3200,IF(B4<68571,5140,IF(B4>68571,6860,0)),0))))))

Comment: Where in your function are you attempting to use 45000 and failing? The first `IF`? The last one?

Comment: If you are trying to round off the number, then the round() function's second argument is in the wrong place. Try: `=IF(B4<20000, 0, IF(B4>20000, ROUND(IF(B4<34286, 685, IF(B4<45714, 1715, IF(B4<57143, 3200, IF(B4<68571, 5140, IF(B4>68571, 6860, 0))))), 0)))`

Answer (score -1):

use:

```
=IF(B4<20000, 0, 
 IF(B4>20000, ROUND(
 IF(B4<34286, 685,
 IF(B4<45714, 1715, 
 IF(B4<57143, 3200, 
 IF(B4<68571, 5140,
 IF(B4>68571, 6860, 0))))), 0)))
```